# SquidProxy HTTPS removing CSS

Tags: squid

Recently, I set up squidproxy on a raspberry pi to block all sites, except the sites defined as 'safe' in a whitelist.

This has worked and I am displayed an 'Access Denied' page if I try to access a site that is not in the whitelist.

One of the sites in the whitelist is a https site, and when I browse to this site using the proxy, I see it in plaintext format (all images and styling have been removed). When I do not use the proxy server, I can see the web page correctly.

I opened up devtools on chrome and I am getting lots of the error:

```
net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

for files, including the CSS sheet on the web page.

What setting do I need to change in squid.conf on the proxy server to allow HTTPS sites to load correctly? Thanks.

Note: As far as I can tell, non HTTPS sites are loading as they should.

Comment: Can you increase the verbosity of that log? One possibility is that the squid proxy is not establishing an ssl connection to the site due to some disabled cipher, certificate issue or similar. A more detailed error could help a lot.

Comment: That's the only error I've got. I don't know where the error log would be located. I've looked in /var/log/squid and it doesn't seem to be there. You say certificate error, but this is happening on all https sites. Surely they can't all have the same error?

Comment: Can you access the https sites on that server without the squid proxy? I mean, direct ssl connections are working from that server?

Comment: I don't have physical access to the server right now, so can't answer at the moment. I will try later.

Comment: One thing I fear is lack of CA certificates or squid not compiled with ssl. If you can validate that things are ok without squid and that it can actually support ssl then it makes sense to advance into config. https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS outlines a few ways to use squid with ssl and their limitations

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try today. I did attempt to configure it with --enable-ssl last night but I must have done something wrong because it still didn't work.